# Resizing graphics window and viewport transformation in JOGL

Tags: java, graphics, viewport, jogl

I am completely beginner in JOGL, only just know it's name and it is used in Computer Graphics. Now what do i want to know if resizing graphics window and viewport transformation is possible in JOGL. If possible, then how it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

Normally, your `reshape()` should looks something like:

```
@Override
public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {

    GL4 gl4 = drawable.getGL().getGL4();

    gl4.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    // update all resources depending on the window size
    // such as the projection matrix
}
```

Comment: reshape is in the class GLEventListener: http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/GLEventListener.html